# displaying list of dates for loop

Tags: php, date

i have this code..that will display a list of month for the current year and the first day of first month and second month

```
$cur_year = date("Y");
$next_year = $cur_year+1;

for($m=1; $m<=12; ++$m)
{
$monthName=date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, 1)).'';
$monthNumber=date('m', mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, 1)).'';
$nextmonth=$monthNumber+1;

echo "$monthName<br />";
echo "$cur_year-$monthNumber-01<br />";
echo "$cur_year-$nextmonth-01<br /><br />";
}
```

i would like to be display like this

```
January
2017-01-01
2017-02-01

February
2017-02-01
2017-03-01

up to December

December
2017-12-01
2018-01-01
```

current ouput

```
January
2017-01-01
2017-2-01

February
2017-02-01
2017-3-01

up to December

December
2017-12-01
2017-13-01
```

Comment: use date functions not just basic math

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `date()` function in PHP

```
<?php
$cur_year  = date('Y');
$next_year = $cur_year + 1;

for ($m = 1; $m <= 12; ++$m)
{
    $monthName  = date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, 1));
    $currentMonthText = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, 1));
    $nextMonthText    = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, $m + 1, 1));

    echo $monthName, '<br />', PHP_EOL;
    echo $currentMonthText, '<br />' . PHP_EOL;
    echo $nextMonthText, '<br />' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "sprintf()".

You edit a line.

```
echo "$cur_year-".sprintf("%02d",$nextmonth)."-01<br /><br />";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<?php

 $cur_year = date("Y");
 $next_year = $cur_year+1;

for($m=1; $m<=12; ++$m)
 {
$monthName=date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, 1)).'';
$monthNumber=date('m', mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, 1)).'';
$nextmonth=$monthNumber+1;

if($nextmonth<10)
  $nextmonth="0".$nextmonth; //will add 0 as prefix to the numbers below 10

echo "$monthName<br>";
echo "$cur_year-$monthNumber-01<br>";
if($nextmonth > 12)
 {
   $cur_year++; //current year +1 2017 to 2018
  $nextmonth="01"; //start the month back to 01 or january
 }
 echo "$cur_year-$nextmonth-01<br><br>";
 }
```